# Suggest EXCEL formula to find first and second defined cell value change in a row

Tags: excel, find, range, formula

I need a suggestion for regular formula (no VBA/no array formulas) to do the following please:

There is the following dataset:

[image]

I need a formula going in the column A and B and returning the month of the first and the second change from 1 to 2 for each row correspondingly.

There are only 1 and 2 being used in the searchable range.

Comment: can one assume theres a `2` if there is a `1` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was really a puzzle :) Please find solution W/O array formula. Make sure you put a number 1 and 2 in cells `A1` and `B1`, because they are part of formula telling which occurrence to take.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$P$1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($E$1:$P$1)-COLUMN($E$1)+1)/($E2:$P2/$D2:$O2=2),A$1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without array formulas and pre-calculcations it is very awkward solution
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B44mzqKXfJYobjNuc0xQRHBaZVU

Use this file for your task. (formulas are inside)
Thank you for + my answer